# Managing Activity using startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 `Activity`s, one is the `MainActivity`, `SubActivity_1` and `SubActivity_2`.
`MainActivity` starts `SubActivity_1`, and `SubActivity_1` starts `SubActivity_2`.

I already know how `startActivityForResult()` works to get from `MainActivity` to `SubActivity_1`.

I start `SubActivity_1` through `MainActivity` with `startActivityForResult()`, then `SubActivity_1` starts `SubActivity_2` and thus closes `SubActivity_1`.

How can i transfer the `onActivityResult()` for `SubActiviyt_1` to `SubActivity_2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close your `SubActivity_1`, in `onActivityResult()` of `MainActivity` start `SubActivity_2` - then it will transfer result to `MainActivity`.